# Entity Framework 5 missing associations

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework

I'm trying to justify using EntityFramework and falling at the very first hurdle. I'm using the database first approach. Here is what it looks like in SQL Server 2008 R2:

[image: db diagram]

As you can see, VERY simple domain. The association is a one-to-many relationship between User.Id and Blog.UserId.

However, even with this incredibly simple domain, EF fails. When I import the tables, I get this:

[image: EF model]

As you can see, there is no association. The relationship is gone and no matter how many times I delete, regenerate, it will not appear. "Include foreign key columns in the model" is checked.

However, if I create the tables based with keys based on ints instead of GUIDs, the relationships are created.

Is this a bug, a limitation or my own stupidity?

It doesn't inspire my confidence. How on earth will it perform in a real-life scenario, with a hundred tables and a thousand associations?

- VS 2012
- SQL Server 2008 R2
- EF 5

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Linq-To-Sql gets it right. The association is discovered and mapped perfectly. What's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've resolved the issue. The problem was caused by a rogue index I did not know I had on the table.

If there is a UNIQUE index on the same field as the primary key, this will cause EF to fail to generate the PK-FK relationship at all.

Simply removing the unnecessary unique index (primary enforces unique anyway), the EF designer immediately picked up the relationship.